# Removing a custom tag from a contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this script that insert a custom tag.

```html
<input type="button" value="my tag" onclick="document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<mytag>'+window.getSelection()+'</mytag>');" />
<main contenteditable="true">Sample text</main>
```

And it works great. But I need the button to remove the tag if the selected text already has it, so it behave more like a toggle action. Any recommendations?

Comment: recommend not using inline function for onclick

Comment: scroll down to "Syntax" on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: @Emily did you find an answer to this question ?

Comment: No yet, still looking!